# Reading and saving untouched .tiff-File with tifffile lib changes file-size and "StripOffsets" and "StripByteCounts" values

Tags: python, arrays, image, computer-vision, tiff

I am trying to work with .tiff files and I want to ensure that I don't alter the files more than intended, so if I don' make any changes, I expect a 100% identical output with same file-size.

To validate that I, initially read and saved a tiff-File to see if there is any unexpected change, and yes, the file-size is  ~3% larger.

This is my code:

```
import tifffile as tiff

image_file = "Image.tiff"
output_file = "Processed_Image.tiff"
image_array = tiff.imread(image_file)
tags = tiff.TiffFile(image_file).pages.pages[0].tags
compression = tags["Compression"].value
rowsperstrip = tags["RowsPerStrip"].value
tiff.imwrite(output_file, image_array, compression=compression, rowsperstrip=rowsperstrip)
```

I can't find a way to add these two tags:

```
tags["StripOffsets"].value
tags["StripByteCounts"].value
```

I analysed the differences of the array itself,`Tiff-Object` and with a tool called `Exiftool.exe` and found out there are differences in `StripOffsets` and `StripByteCounts`, but the compression, shape and array-values are identical (`np.array_equal()` returns `True`)

I tried to pass over as many arguments to the `imwrite()` function as possible, so it doesn't use unwanted default values to change the image.

Comment: You can't control StripOffsets or StripByteCounts. Those are set by tifffile depending on where exactly the compressed image data is written to in the file. Tifffile writes strips contiguously but it doesn't matter according to the TIFF specification (as long as the strips are not overlapping of course).